# Application type of .Z file type

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip, compression

I'm trying to find the application type in order  to figure if a file is a 'compressed' file using the File command.
The compress files have the .Z file type, and I want to catch it using the ' case ... in ' method.
An example for catching gunzip files will be the following:

```
            case $(file --mime-type -b "$myFile") in
            application/gzip) 
                echo "gunzip    $myFile" ;;
```

I've tried doing this:

```
                application/ncompress)
                echo "uncompress    $myFile" ;; # NOT WORKING
```

But it does not work.

Comment: What does `file "$myfile"` say about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because that's not what file says? I get `application/x-compress` for .Z files.

Comment: application/x-compress works!